# Won't vs wouldn't

Tags: will-would

What is the difference in the usage of "won't" and "wouldn't" in these sentences:

```
The bathroom is filthy. I won't even wash my socks in it.
The bathroom is filthy. I wouldn't even wash my socks in it.
```

I know that "wouldn't" expresses refusal in the past but what does it mean in this sentence (if it's correct of course)?

Comment: The difference is the same as "what you *will* do" vs. "what you *would* do".

Answer (score 3):

**wouldn't** isn't only the past tense; it can also be used in a conditional or hypothetical sense.

"I *won't* even wash my socks in it" is a simple factual statement that I will not do it.

"I *wouldn't* even wash my socks in it" is essentially saying "I would not use it for anything, even washing my socks."  It's like saying "Wash my face in that bathroom?  I wouldn't even wash my socks in there" but we don't always say it so verbosely.

Comment: So when use "won't" it means that I really have to wash my socks somewhere but it won't be in that bathroom. Compared to "wouldn't" where I don't have to wash my socks but say that "If I had to wash them, I wouldn't wash them in thath bathroom".. Is that right?

Comment: Mostly, yes.  I don't think it is usually so specific, but "I won't even wash my socks in there" slightly implies that I do wash my socks somewhere, but not in that bathroom, while "I wouldn't even wash my socks in there" says "Even if I did have to wash my socks, it would not be in there".

Comment: Yeah, sure! Thanks a lot! Now I have trouble with another usage of would - would & would have. Look at these 2 sentences: No one would guess he lives in a fancy house. and: No one would have guessed he lived in a fancy house. Do they mean the same? Actually are they correct?